# How to pass a pdf_file to a parser method in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, form-for, pdf-reader

i'm a newbie into rails development and i can't found a solution for that.

I have a model with an attached file (i'm using paperclip) to upload.

```
has_attached_file :program
```

So, i have a method that receives one of these files and parse it using PDFReader gem.
I've passed the program object but i'm getting this error:

```
ArgumentError - input must be an IO-like object or a filename:
```

If i pass **program.filename** as the parameter i get an error 'undefined method' although that seems that filename method lives into the # object (that appears in the server log)

Comment: Try to use pdf reader gem for more info check here https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader

Comment: I'm using this gem (i've to edit my post). The problem is related to the route to call the method that parse the file and not with the parser.

Comment: R u using pdf reader gem?

Comment: The most likely cause is the filename you are providing is not a valid file.

Comment: Yes, i'm using pdf reader gem. When the gem tries to open the file an error occurs. Why a recently uploaded file could be an invalid file for the gem? How to call the PDF Reader initializer?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the CarrierWave gem. It's more flexible/powerful, and pretty well-documented. https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

Comment: Thank's for the recommendation, but i'm not the project owner and i have to find a solution with these (non-functional) requirements.